# What can I do if I have a colleague who is picking on me?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, communication, colleagues

I have a colleague who is making unrelated non-professional remarks (for example she criticized the socks I was wearing last time). It looks like that she is frustrated and this is her strategy to relieve stress.

We are not on the same project, we don't even talk and she is sitting at the opposite end of the room. I don't have the slightest idea what could be the problem but this is getting pretty annoying.

Last time I confronted her with her behavior and she made obscure comments about astrological topics and told me that it is her way or the highway. None of which made any sense to me. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Ignore her and buy lots of the socks that she commented on and wear them every day!

Comment: Well it may be a good idea.

Comment: _Ask her to buy a good pair of socks for you._

Comment: I really start to get the funny ideas here :)

Comment: Do all of these on her: http://voices.yahoo.com/20-quick-easy-pranks-pull-co-workers-591944.html

Comment: "astrological topics?" That's an unmistakable sign (no pun intended) that you're dealing with a flake.

Comment: Sometimes people behave annoying like this because they have a crush on you!

Comment: What is love? Baby don't hurt me~

Comment: Love byte, I say!!

Comment: A corn flake? :D

Comment: Ask her out on a date, that should end it fast.

Comment: concur with @GregMcNulty

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Two part answer:

If you do not need to work and interact with this person - don't. Ignore and block her out - as completely as possible. Do not answer any questions. Do not respond to anything she says. Don't answer emails from her. This should help as if this is a bully, getting no reaction will most probably make them stop as it is not a satisfying result.

If, however, you do have to work with this person:

Since your colleague persists in spite of being confronted by you (I assume you have asked her to stop this behaviour during your confrontations), it is time to take this to a higher level.

Talk to your manager - if your manager is also the manager of this person, all the better.

Explain the problem, explain how this behaviour makes the workplace an unpleasant place and that the remarks are unprofessional and demeaning to both yourself and the colleague. Tell your manager that you want this behaviour to stop and explain what you have already done in order to try and stop it.

If your manager agrees with your assessment of the behaviour or that this person is indeed the problem (they may not agree... think about this possibility before moving on). It is possible that for political or professional reasons, they can't do anything, but assuming they can, this will now be their responsibility. You can report future transgressions to your manager, as they happen and hope things will turn to the best.

What you should not do, under any circumstance is engage in reciprocal behaviour - that will just fuel the behaviour of this colleague and will end up in a tit-for-tat escalation.

Comment: I just told her that I don't really care about her non-professional opinions and she either stops it or I'll start to ignore her.

Comment: @Adam - fine. If you do not need to interact with her, don't. Completely block her out. Completely.

Comment: @AdamArold do record any inappropriate emails from her so when it gets out of hand you have evidence

Comment: I'm not planning to let this escalate. I don't e-mail with her either.

Comment: @AdamArold You may not email her now... Don't be afraid to make these statements via email. I would lean towards sending these messages via email, to show prior efforts if things escalate - your intention or not. Verbal contact is step one. Document everything after that. Notarize. BCC your boss. CYA.

Answer (score 15):

There may be a number of reasons why she is doing this.  She may just be an eccentric person with a bizarre personality.  If this is the case then there is probably little you can do but just ignore her.  We are forced to deal with people in the workplace that we otherwise would never associate with.

The other possibility may be that she *likes* you and this is her poor attempt at flirting.  It is not uncommon for people to be picky and hyper critical towards others they are developing feelings for, especially for nonsensical things like the socks you are wearing.  If this is the case then take it as you will.

Comment: I just discussed this matter with my other colleague and he thinks that the behavior of my colleague in question is the same towards the others. She tends to make non-related annoying remarks. I just did not notice this so far. He told me that this is a shirt-sleeve workplace in his opinion and this kind of behavior is acceptable.

Comment: @AdamArold that sort of behavior is never acceptable.  Unfortunately if your colleague's opinion is widely held by the company getting management intervention may be difficult to impossible; and the situation may come down to working with a jerk or finding alternate employment.

Answer (score 12):

Having worked with some unpleasant people I simply suggest you ignore this behavior, she is probably trying to get some reaction from you. If you don't react you take the fun out of it.

If you need to work with her, do your tasks as usual but whenever she makes an unpleasant comment you simply shrug and go away. You don't need to like every person you work with and you don't need to entertain their uncivil behavior, you need to do your job.

However, you do need to update your manager about it, unless he/she is already aware of it, you need to say that you are going to perform your work but this behavior is making you extremely uncomfortable.

Good luck

Answer (score 8):

Unless there's some sort of cultural difference I'm missing (I'm from Australia), I find it weird that nobody has brought up the very probable reality that you're taking offence over nothing.

The fact that it's something like an insult over sock colour suggests to me that she's just trying to lightheartedly jest with people, to lighten up the workplace a little bit. Some people are better at this than others but I find it impossible to believe that anybody would do this with the intention of harassing or embarrassing you. Just laugh it off and take a stab back at her.

Comment: I don't want to hear these. For example every day she complains about the time I arrive at the company. I'm not late but I arrive later than her and she just says "Good evening" (at 9 AM) and all kinds of variations to this. And this is going on all day. Not just to me but to others too. I'm not the only one who got fed up with this. The socks was just one example.

Comment: What's her tone of voice like though? Because the issue is radically different if she's saying it normally to if she's saying it in a stern or condescending tone.

Answer (score 4):

Have her supervisor, or the first "common" link in the chain of command between you and her, disillusion her of the notion that it is "her way or the highway"; it is in fact her manager's way or the highway. If that discussion does not occur (first common link in the chain is too high up to care about the drama of the little people, or more likely her immediate supervisor likes her or is afraid of her too much to be direct with her), then you take it to HR.

If someone is making personal attacks against you, and direct in-person confrontation including a direct request to stop did not resolve the issue, then you escalate the issue until it gets dealt with. That may or may not include termination of anyone's employment, and if your co-worker keeps her job she will resent you for whatever disciplinary action actually occurred. She should be smart enough to keep that to herself; if not, you know where to go if the unpleasantness continues.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword here is harassment (which she is doing).

Tell your manager she is harassing you - **legally he will have to do something to end it**.

> The employer will be liable for harassment by non-supervisory
>   employees or non-employees over whom it has control (e.g., independent
>   contractors or customers on the premises), if it knew, or should have
>   known about the harassment and failed to take prompt and appropriate
>   corrective action.

So basically your boss will need to address it.

[EEOC](http://www.eeoc.gov/laws/practices/harassment.cfm)

[Harassment in the Workplace: It's Against the Law - www.state.ia.us](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=us%20workplace%20harassment%20laws&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://www.state.ia.us/government/crc/docs/WorkplaceHarassment_July08.pdf&ei=kI6lUMqDKuSx0AGG6YCQDA&usg=AFQjCNEquoUuiLYRqUYOFpNynB1i-8mMyQ)

[What Speech Does "Hostile Work Environment" Harassment Law Restrict?](http://www2.law.ucla.edu/volokh/harass/breadth.htm)

Comment: This is a simple and good answer that may not be right.  Think about the outcomes-if HR (or whoever investigates) thinks you are right they need to solve it.  If not, you get a downgrade.  What are the odds, how much better off are you if you win, what is the cost if you lose?

Comment: The legal route is long winded and the end of the day there is rarely winners on all sides. However the manager is obligated to do something about it, because if it does turn into a harassment case it is the company that gets sued, not the person causing the harassment.

Comment: If you are going to make a claim like *legally he will have to do something to end it.* this you need to **back it up** with a link to the law that requires it or something else to back up that statement.  Harrassment laws do no protect you from someone else being a jack ass.

Comment: @Chad: these harassment laws are basic standards in all American companies.

Comment: @GregMcNulty - So then it should not be difficult for you to back up your claim with references.

Comment: harassement is a bit much she only criticized a pair of socks.

Comment: Your answer now says that you could get monetary damages from your employer not that they actually have to end it.  On top of that you have not established that saying your socks are ugly is harassment.

Comment: This answer assumes the question is about the U.S. As I type this the OP's profile says he is in Hungary.

Answer (score -2):

IGNORE completely. Don't even answer, or show any reaction. That's the way I got rid of a cranky person around my me. I know its very annoying, use your headphones even if you don't hear any music. Pretend that you don't even see!

Comment: We are no longer working to gether. I moved to a new employer.

Comment: @AdamArold you moved to a new employer just because of this lady?

Comment: No. I moved to a new employer because they made an offer and the project was interesting for me. It had nothing to do with the lady.